# Swipe down or pull down to access next View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create the ability to swipe down to access the next view controller or in other words I want to pull down the view controller from the top. I created a sample of how i want it to look and work using a scrollview. The problem when trying to use that method however was that I am no longer able to interact with the first view because the scrollview is covering it.

I want the top view to cover the bottom one when it is pulled in. I also want it to be in sync with the users finger, the same way the scroll view with paging enabled does in my gif example.

[image]

Comment: Add nextviewcontroller in self as a childviewcontroller then add it in nextviewcontroller.view in self.view & add animation top to bottom.

Comment: I believe that you want to add something like this: [link](https://github.com/soapyigu/Swift30Projects/tree/master/Project%2015%20-%20SnapchatMenu). I hope it gives some idea to you.

Comment: @ridvankucuk That is similar to what i want to do but i want the new view to cover the current view not move it out of the way